# Filter for rows in excel sheet

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with columns voter ID, Party, city, year last voted, age, ballot status
I want to make a filter that shows rows (or just voterID list) with
city="ABC", party="xyz", age >=35 and age <=55   as well as
city="sydney" and year last voted >2019
I need assistance in creating a filter. With so many conditions, this seems confusing.
The following rows should be shown:
123, xyz, ABC, ... , 40, ...
130, ..., sydney,2020,..,...

The ... means the value doesn't matter here as it satisfies one of the
two given conditions

Comment: Can you describe the OR condition in more detail? Is it (age = ... OR city= ...)?

Comment: @Rory I have updated the question, to make it more clear. Let me know if it makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: I'm not following your OR condition in this revised version well either... can you provide an example?

Comment: @dnaiel A data example and expected output would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

City, Party: Use the regular filter

[image: City Photo]

Age, Year: Use number filters

[image]

Comment: Once I created a filter on City column, after that I am unable to create a filter on age column, when I select the column values, click on Data, it shows remove filter option. 
Clicking on which basically removes the filter on the City column.

Comment: The filter is like conditional, so like if the year voted is after 2019 and city is sydney we include that row. I am not sure how to make a conditional filter

Comment: See the down arrow in my column headers in the pictures? Create the filters using the dropdown arrow on the column header. Added a new photo to show it.